# Sharepoint 2013 Serach Rest API URL Limitation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-search

I am using sharepoint search rest API to get the products. Here I am facing strange issue if the length of query url is less than 1800 characters I am getting response from api(verified just pasting the url in the browser) but if the length is more than 1800 I am getting web page not found here I am assuming sharepoint search api not able to manage the url length greater than 1800. Is it limitation of sharepoint search API?

My query goes like this 
https://www.example.com/_api/search/query?querytext='ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1 OR ItemId:1'&SourceId='8e4r54e0-0a21-4525-9311-9b6dcdc7f626'&SelectProperties='ItemId,Path,Image'&QueryTemplatePropertiesUrl='spfile://webroot/queryparametertemplate.xml'

Answer (score 0):

It could be that IIS can not handle the long URL. IIS default maximum length for an URL is 260 characters.

To fix it, you can increase the maxURLlength value, add it to your web.config file in the IIS virtual Directory.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="5000" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```